# Android - Maximum characters in email app

Tags: android, email

I'm developing an Android email app. What character limit should I set for the subject and message text?

Answer (score 0):

Official e-mail specification is available here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822 It must be specified somewhere in section 2.2.